# How to uninstall python 3.9.6

Tags: 20.04, python3

I actually have 3 different python interpreters:

- Python 2.7.8 (I know that 2.7.8 comes with Ubuntu)
- Python 3.8.10 (I use it for daily python projects)
- Python 3.9.6 (I don't use it any time)

so I want to get rid of Python 3.9.6

How can I only uninstall Python 3.9.6?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.9?

Comment: Ubuntu does not install 2.7 by default anymore. There are one or two old applications that have not been converted & installing those will install 2.7. I will not install any app that wants to install 2.7. Do not change Ubuntu's default version of python. You break things. It used to be total reinstall was only fix, if you removed default python., Now it may be fixed, but not particularly easy.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 comes with 93.9.5 so this 3.9.6 has been self installed on 20.04. Indeed, it could be uninstalled depending on how the OP installed it in the first place.

Comment: ok Thankyou All

Answer (score 0):

This will likely work.

```
sudo apt uninstall python3.9
```